# How to get values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get strings from a long array value.

for example

```
$array[1]='this is a good day. The number:1, class:math';
$array[2]='this is a bad day. The number:2, class:english';
$array[3]='this is a fine day. The number:3, class:physics';
```

I want to get the `number:1` or `class:math` strings out of the array.

I tried

```
echo array_search('number:1',$array);
```

but it gave me nothing. I was wondering if there are better ways to do this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) yet?

Comment: `array_search` searches array elements, not the contents of strings in array elements. Are you attempting to find the *element* containing *a certain key/value pair*, or are you attempting to find *the value of a certain key in a certain element*?

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying do to?  What did you want that to return?

Comment: see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp, specifically under "Multidimensional Arrays"

Comment: You're searching a string.  I'd suggest trying to use an appropriate [String Function](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: I want to get part of the contents out of the array. For example, The number:1 or class:math.

Comment: @FlyingCat: So you just want to know if any of the strings contain a certain string?

Comment: You're going to have to try harder at explaining what you need, how you want it to be used, what you expect to be returned, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're searching for something like the following. Searching for a needle inside of values of arrays.

```
<?php
function array_search_inline($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $needle) !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Note: `array_search` simply compares the array's values and does not search inside of them.

Comment: I think you meant `strpos($value, $needle)` ?

Comment: Shouldn't you make it `array_search_inline($needle, $haystack)` to be consistent?

Comment: Thanks both. I just used the function header of strpos($haystack, $needle), before...

Comment: PHP hates all of us, and randomly reverses the order of `$needle` and `$haystack`. Most `array_` functions, though, are consistent among themselves.